# How to set up Python3 with SQLite 3 and SpatiaLite on MacOS

Tags: python, gdal, spatialite, sqlite, macos

I've developed a converter for spatial data which currently runs on Windows and Linux in Python3. On Windows I need to exchange the given sqlite3.dll for the original one from the SQLite website, for the converter needs the rtree module.
Now I need to get the converter running on MacOS (to which I'm quite new).

I have installed the MacOs-Python3-package from python.org, and via homebrew added GDAL and SpatiaLite. But Python3 and its SQLite installation seems to lack a couple of needed capabilities - so I can't even load the spatialite-module, as Python keeps telling me that some capabilities are lacking...

Can anybody tell me how to set up the environment on MacOS?

---

I followed the instructions given in the article - if I enter "sqlite3" at the command prompt the correct version (3.36.something) is given. But after starting my python3 script I still get the error-message:

```
AttributeError: 'sqlite3.Connection' object has no attribute 'enable_load_extension'
```

So, what can I do to make python recognize the new SQLite-version.

---

I again fiddled around a bit - with still no success. What I've tried so far: I removed al python3 installations; installed SQLite 3 following the instructions - SQLite3 tells me that loading modules is enabled; I installed libspatialite via homebrew; I then installed python3 via homebrew - this all results in the same AttributeError telling me that SQLite is not able to load extension. So I guess python still points to the original SQLite3 version. Is there a way to make python point to the correct version?

Comment: [Installing and using SQLite extensions on macOs (and maybe Windows & Linux too)](https://www.cafe-encounter.net/p3244/installing-and-using-sqlite-extensions-on-macos-and-maybe-windows-linux-too)

Comment: Did you have to change your environment path at all?